# computedFrom array won't update when push()ing, but works if reassigning

Tags: aurelia

I guess there's some reason behind this, but if I have an array in my VM and `push()` to it, my `@computedFrom` method won't update. If I instead use `concat()` (and essentially accomplish the same thing as the push would) it *does* update:

```
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyVm {
    constructor () {
        this.list = [{name: 'Foo', id: 0, open: true}, {name: 'Bar', id: 1, open: false}];

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.list.push({name: 'Baz', id: 2, open: true}); // This won't update numOpenListItems
            this.list = this.list.concat([{name: 'Baz', id: 2, open: true}]); // This will
        });
    }

    @computedFrom('list')
    get numOpenListItems () {
        return this.list.filter(item => item.open === true).length;
    }
}
```

For code clarity (and likely performance) I'd prefer to use `push()`, is there any way I can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, `computedFrom` uses property observers, not array observers.

To solve your problem, I'd take a step back and not use `computedFrom` with a getter at all. When you want to force array subscription, use a **binding signaler**.

**home.html**

```
<div with.bind="list | open & signal: 'store:add'">
  ${length}
</div>
```

**home.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { BindingSignaler } from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class HomeViewModel

    constructor(signaler) {
        this.signaler = signaler
    }

    add(store) {
        this.list.push(store)
        this.signaler.signal('store:add')
    }
}
```

Here's a working example: https://gist.run/?id=9681fab58b1b6494dfdca13e018ff3e9

Also, I've written an all purpose filter value converter called Bouncer. You can check it out here (http://foursails.github.io/bouncer/) or grab the source here (https://github.com/Foursails/bouncer).

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but if I push a new element to the list array in a setTimeout it doesn't seem to update :/ https://gist.run/?id=64dee66cf0a682f2610529f7445ab47c

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer and it is working for the your gist above.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say it's better to use a signaler than to simply concat? Imo the concat code is easier to read and I don't have to first add my item, then tell _certain_ UIs to update, I just add my item and the _entire_ UI gets updated - regardless if they're using the 'store:add' signaler. This is the main reason I like working with a framework like Aurelia, I don't have to "manually" update my UI. And this kind of defeats that purpose imo. Is there no way to tell Aurelia that my observable (or whatever it's called) _is_ an array so that push would work?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head, but I believe there are performance implications in using the concat. I believe concat generates a new array, and depending on your code, you might have multiple copies of the same array floating around your app if you use concat extensively.

Then again, the first rule of optimization is: don't. And the second rule: Not yet. So you may want to go the concat route after all.

Comment: One thing though, I find it annoying that the view (that displays the list) _does_ update, but my computedFrom does not. I really don't understand why they should be different.

Comment: Lets say we have an object `vm = { records: [1,2,3] }`. There are two kinds of changes we can make to records. We can do stuff to the array (which is just an object) by calling array methods like push: `vm.records.push(4)`. Or we can change the array. `vm.records = ['a','b','c']`. Aurelia binding listens for the latter kind of change, for arrays and all other objects, and updates on those bindings. Array methods like `push` are a special case that isn't supported yet.

Comment: But `push` does work for just updating the view? That's why it's slightly annoying that it _doesn't_ work for updating my `@computedFrom`

Comment: It only works for updating a `repeat.for` binding, which *requires* an iterable.